# Setting of delete entities from Azure Table Storage by Azure Logic App

Tags: azure, azure-logic-apps

I need help with following problem ...

I have set-up Azure Data Factory (DF) process which copying data from Storage Table into Azure SQL Database. Now I need deleting data from Storage Table after succeful copy to SQL. I'm trying do it over Web Action in DF, where I call Azure Logic App with Delete Entity step. 
Everything working well when I'm sending debug entries for Partition Key and Row Key - entity is corectly deleted. But I can't found way, how I can send all Part/Row keys from source Table Storage to Logic App for deleting ... :-/
I was trying some setting about dynamic content in DF pipeline, but without success ...

BTW ... I was inspired by this article, but there is not complete description of solution for my problem ... https://kromerbigdata.com/2018/03/15/azure-data-factory-delete-from-azure-blob-storage-and-table-storage/

Comment: Please share (sample or real) code that you wrote, so that you can get better help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the source table name and you want delete all entities, you could get the all entities firstly, then use a for each action to delete them all. The below is my test flow.

[image]

The output is the table entities:`@body('Get_entities')?['value']`, and the partition key and the row key are:`@{encodeURIComponent(items('For_each')?['PartitionKey'])}` and `@{encodeURIComponent(items('For_each')?['RowKey'])}`. Also you could get them from Dynamic content like the below picture.

[image]